# ODT to PDF Converter

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

We have a need to replace LibreOffice headless as a **ODT-to-PDF** converter.
The software we are looking should have to following requirements:

- Convert a massive number (as a batch process) of ODT documents to PDF.
- Realtime, concurent conversion of ODT documents
- Preferably should be Linux oriented

Comment: You may recall why you need to replace LibreOfffice. Not fast enough?

Comment: You might have a look at [pandoc](www.pandoc.org). I like this software, but didn't have the occasion to test it for that purpose. Should do it if I am not wrong.

Comment: Libreoffice seems to have concurency issues and also might have some kind of mem leaks since we see it failing from time to time, especially on a large amount of batch conversions.

Comment: Since Linux is just preferably would Windows tool feat as well? Can it be comercial tool?

Comment: I just made a test with pandoc. Unfortunately, it appears that the conversion does not work well in this case, Even worse than with .docx -> pdf. Sorry

Comment: We would like to avoid Windows. It  can be a commercial tool.

Comment: While Pandoc was my first thought, too, you could also give [Calibre](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html) a look (link goes to the corresponding documentation page, showing options e.g. for ODT input and PDF output). Have not tried it for that, though, due to lack of demand for batch processing ODT->PDF (I use it for HTML=>EPUB where it works fine).

Comment: So if there is no way to avoid Windows, MultiDoc Converter could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[odt-to-pdf-converter](https://github.com/javadev/odt-to-pdf-converter/blob/master/odttopdf.zip) and [docs-to-pdf-converter](https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter/releases) are both free document converters writen in Java, so they should work with Linux. While the first one has GUI the other is just command line and some kind of open sorce. And if there is no way around Windows, [TEbookConverter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/autokindle/?source=typ_redirect) could be a solution, it´s free too.